# How do I fix Twilio SMS send error when sending vcard via zapier

Tags: twilio, zapier

I am trying to send a vcard via Twilio when a subscriber is added to my mailchimp list. I am using zapier for the integration. All the steps work, except when adding the vcard.

When the message is sent I get the following error message: "Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL. Please see the [Twilio Markup XML Documentation](/docs/api/twiml/) for more information on valid Content-Types."

I understand that vcard/text is a supported type. the file is stored at https://gallery.mailchimp.com/485f8f63814a122cf8435a4ee/files/cd3791fc-83c0-469a-9029-a4a0341fe82f/johnmenke.vcf

Twilio seemed to pick up the file and read the information (the text is dsiplayed in my account), can anyone help me understand what I have wrong? I'm in the US, in case that matters.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just `curl`ed that URL and the response content type was `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` which is not a supported MIME type.

If you serve the file as `text/vcard` it should be fine. You may find that where you have hosted it can't provide the right response content type, so you may need to host it elsewhere.

Comment: Brilliant! Would you be able to mark the answer as correct so that others can see it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx to serve files, you may need to add the vcard as a mime type. Some installations of nginx do not have vcard as a default mime type. For example, your nginx.conf file may contain a line like the following:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

And you will want to add the vcard mime type, so just append the following lines to the nginx.conf file:

```
types {
  # here are additional types
  text/vcard vcard vcf;
}
```